# magento 1.9.1.1 permission error - 403 forbidden

Tags: ce-1.9.1.1

I tried to install the latest magento 1.9.1.1 at my cpanel host. But it occurred a 403 forbidden error when I visited my site to install...

I checked that some files with 640 permission, but not 644.  So I think there is little error with this official 1.9.1.1 zip file. Is anybody came across this issue?

Comment: the permissions might be changed when you extracted. Make sure to fix them and try again. There's a lengthy tutorial on how to install Magento on their website, I'm pretty sure they're talking about setting permissions, too

Comment: Thanks! But I don't know why the permissions changed when I extracted... Everything goes well when I tried to install 1.9.1.0 at the same cpanel...

Comment: yes that's weird. On the other hand, what does it matter ;) if you really think it's a bug, feel free to report it to Magento though

Comment: try to install in localhost and then move the files to server is always better!!!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Updating system-wide file permissions after unzipping/extracting the .zip and make sure you're in the root directory of your [Magento](https://ultimatecheckout.com/) instance. Then run these commands

```
    find ./ -type f | xargs chmod 644
    find ./ -type d | xargs chmod 755
    chmod -Rf 777 var
    chmod -Rf 777 media
```