# Can't access admin or magento connect get 403 permission forbidden error when I tried to update extensions

Tags: magento-1.9

When I'm trying to update extensions from 1.9.2.1 to 1.9.3.6, it gives me 403 permission forbidden error. What should I do?

Comment: Regarding to your description, you should be trying to update the core, isn't it? The modules with `Magento_` prefix are core files.

Comment: It might help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/69721/21339

Answer (score 1):

Check permission of `/downloader/` folder if permission is not `755` then set it to `755` and check permission of /downloader/index.php file and set to `644`.

If this not work then backup your `downloader` folder and download fresh magento setup and upload only `downloader` folder into your root directory.

Hope that will work for you, it's work for me.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get into the downloader but the website URL and the admin still give me a 403 perfmission forbidden error.